# How to add to months in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am a week old in angular and in my application(angular 7)  i have used owldate picker, and with that date, i need to increment 3 months to the selected date. say 'Value' comes from the datepicker, When i do `value.getMonth()`, it returns 11 always . I have also tried using momentjs,

```
 import * as moment from 'moment'
    ..........
   newDate :moment.Moment
   newDate= value 
    constructor(){
     this.newDate .add(3,'months');
      }
```

this returns an error: "_this.nwrdate.add is not a function". I am stuck here!!  maybe its very basic, but i am stuck here!

Comment: Is it a typo here or in your code that `newDate` and `this.nwrDate`?

Comment: sorry typo, my bad , i will change it!
--update changed

Comment: Is the value coming from the datepicker in `Moment` type? If not, you should convert the `value` to a proper `Moment` object.

Comment: @jungNitesh `value.getMonth()` will always be 11. Since, it doesn't change. What changes is `newDate` variable. Try `this.newDate.get('month')`, it will show you 3 months ahead value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

constructor() {

    let now = moment();
    console.log(now.format());
    // This line adds 3 moths to your date
    console.log(now.add(3, 'months').format()); 

}
```

Let me know if you need more help